# How to convert a uint to bytes in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, bytes

Is there an easy way to convert a `uint` to `bytes` in Solidity?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It seems there now is, since solidity version 0.4.24 you can use [abi.encodePacked](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.10/abi-spec.html?highlight=encodepacked#non-standard-packed-mode)

E.G:

```
uint i = 0;
i_bytes = abi.encodePacked(i);
```

Answer (score 32):

The alternative to @eth's answer is to use assembly:

```
function toBytes(uint256 x) returns (bytes b) {
    b = new bytes(32);
    assembly { mstore(add(b, 32), x) }
}
```

This is significantly more gas-efficient, but depends on the internal memory layout used by the Solidity compiler. In theory, this can change in future, but in practice it should be fairly stable.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what each line does? What is the purpose of this add(b, 32). Couldn't we simply do mstore(b, x)?

Comment: @ppoliani did you get an answer to your question? I am also curious why we add 32 to b. (when b should be at the start of memory address anyway).

Comment: Actually it is explained here:
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/98750/what-does-addsource-32-do-in-solidity

Comment: @ppoliani the `bytes` type in Solidity is stored in memory as: 1) first 32 bytes = length of the `bytes` value, 2) then the `bytes` value itself. The `mstore` opcode stores 32 bytes, starting from a certain offset (in the bytes value to grab) to a specified location in memory. So the instruction `mstore(add(b, 32), x)` can be translated in plain words as _"stores 32 bytes at position x in memory, starting from the 32nd bytes offset in the `b`"_ (so to skip the length, and just store `b` itself).

Answer (score 18):

Here's a comparison of the gas used in the three methods by @NickJohnson, @Eth and @k26dr. I've added a `constant` to the function modifiers as these functions do not alter the blockchain:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

contract Test {
    function toBytesNickJohnson(uint256 x) constant returns (bytes b) {
        b = new bytes(32);
        assembly { mstore(add(b, 32), x) }
    }

    function toBytesEth(uint256 x) constant returns (bytes b) {
        b = new bytes(32);
        for (uint i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
            b[i] = byte(uint8(x / (2**(8*(31 - i))))); 
        }
    }

    function toBytesNicolasMassart(uint256 x) constant returns (bytes c) {
        bytes32 b = bytes32(x);
        c = new bytes(32);
        for (uint i=0; i < 32; i++) {
            c[i] = b[i];
        }
    }    
}
```

You can see the gas cost of running these functions in Remix (Solidity Browser):

[image]

Answer (score 7):

There are no easy ways to convert anything to `bytes`. Here's a function:

```
function toBytes(uint256 x) returns (bytes b) {
    b = new bytes(32);
    for (uint i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        b[i] = byte(uint8(x / (2**(8*(31 - i))))); 
    }
}
```

Based on [Solidity Gitter chat.](https://gitter.im/ethereum/solidity?at=56b8a608939ffd5d15f66e99)

Answer (score 5):

If you're overly concerned about gas we can improve on @NickJohnson answer too.

```
function toBytes(uint _num) returns (bytes _ret) {
    assembly {
        _ret := mload(0x10)
        mstore(_ret, 0x20)
        mstore(add(_ret, 0x20), _num)
    }
}
```

This will shave approximately a further 15% off the gas cost, just be careful that you're not using that memory for something else as 0x10 is a direct reference to memory.

Also, if you want to copy an 8bit int to byte here's an alternative which only uses half the gas cost:

```
function toByte(uint8 _num) returns (byte _ret) {
    assembly {
        mstore8(0x20, _num)
        _ret := mload(0x20)
    }
}
```

Again, be mindful that 0x20 is another direct memory reference and in all honesty with this one I would stick with

```
function toByte(uint8 _num) returns (byte _ret) {
    return byte(_num);
}
```

The gas price between the two was almost identical, but the functional ASM was undercutting it by about 70 wei

Edit: If you're concerned about overwriting memory you could use:

```
let m_alloc := add(msize(),0x1)
```

Instead of referencing memory yourself

Comment: I didn't know msize() can be used to increase the memory allocation by adding to it. The solidity assembly document (https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/assembly.html?highlight=calldatacopy) is very brief. Is there a better reference document out there?

Comment: msize doesn't, it returns the highest point in memory and you simply state that you want to write to msize() plus 1. Here's another stack page where I explain it in more detail https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9537/how-to-return-dynamic-sized-arrays-original-address-on-the-memory-of-solidity

Answer (score 2):

You can convert to bytes32 then convert to bytes:

```
uint u = 200;
bytes32 b = bytes32(u);
bytes memory c = new bytes(32);
for (uint i=0; i < 32; i++) {
    c[i] = b[i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid padding the bytes array with 0's with the `toBytes` implementations by determining the scriptNumSize

```
function scriptNumSize(uint256 i) public view returns (uint256) {
    if      (i > 0x7fffffff) { return 5; }
    else if (i > 0x7fffff  ) { return 4; }
    else if (i > 0x7fff    ) { return 3; }
    else if (i > 0x7f      ) { return 2; }
    else if (i > 0x00      ) { return 1; }
    else                     { return 0; }
}

function toBytes(uint256 x) public view returns (bytes memory b) {
    uint a = scriptNumSize(x);
    b = new bytes(a);
    for (uint i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        b[i] = byte(uint8(x / (2**(8*(a - 1 - i))))); 
    }
}
```

For example uint 1563384765 would return 0x5d2f5bbd not 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005d2f5bbd

This was written specifically for timestamps. If you want larger numbers you can add more if cases.