# How to convert a uint256 type integer into a bytes32?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, bytes32, uint256, type-casting

Since both types, uint256's and bytes32's space are 2^256. How to map an uint256 type integer into bytes32 type in Solidity ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a uint to bytes in Solidity?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4170/how-to-convert-a-uint-to-bytes-in-solidity)

Comment: @RichardHorrocks It doesn't seem to be exactly the same question.

Comment: I think that if we have `bytes32 b` and `uint256 u`, then we can do `b =  bytes32(u)` and `u = uint256(b)`. Sorry, can't check now.

Comment: I'm being a bit trigger-happy with the dupes. Apologies - I'll reel it in. Credit to @Ismael.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just use `bytes32(u)`.  It's as easy as that because they are both 2^256 (unlike `bytes`).

No need for a separate function, but to clarify:

```
function convert(uint256 n) returns (bytes32) {
    return bytes32(n);
}
```

Comment: No longer works in solidity ^0.8.0.

Comment: @JanBeneš actually it still works in v0.8 - I used `v0.8.15+commit.e14f2714` to compile this code and it worked.