# Conversion of uint to string

Tags: solidity, string

I am trying to convert **uint** to **string** in solidity. Is it possible to convert? if so how can I convert it?

Convertion to base 10 is prefered, but in hexadecimal might also be helpful.

Comment: You should specify what do you want as result, it is not unique. For instance: do you want an hex format output? Do you want a bin output? Do you want the base 10 number? Do you want an hex with uppercase for letter? And so on.

Answer (score 17):

Another option is to use a solution from Oraclize https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/blob/master/oraclizeAPI_0.5.sol, it suits best for me:

**0.5 Compiler Version:**

```
    function uint2str(uint _i) internal pure returns (string memory _uintAsString) {
    if (_i == 0) {
        return "0";
    }
    uint j = _i;
    uint len;
    while (j != 0) {
        len++;
        j /= 10;
    }
    bytes memory bstr = new bytes(len);
    uint k = len - 1;
    while (_i != 0) {
        bstr[k--] = byte(uint8(48 + _i % 10));
        _i /= 10;
    }
    return string(bstr);
}
```

**Pre 0.5 Compiler Version:**

```
function uint2str(uint i) internal pure returns (string){
    if (i == 0) return "0";
    uint j = i;
    uint length;
    while (j != 0){
        length++;
        j /= 10;
    }
    bytes memory bstr = new bytes(length);
    uint k = length - 1;
    while (i != 0){
        bstr[k--] = byte(48 + i % 10);
        i /= 10;
    }
    return string(bstr);
}
```

Comment: This does not work with solidity 0.8.0

Answer (score 10):

You can convert the uint to bytes32 by using `bytes32 data = bytes32(u)` (uint is same uint256 [How to convert a uint256 type integer into a bytes32?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6498/how-to-convert-a-uint256-type-integer-into-a-bytes32))

Then use [How to convert a bytes32 to string](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2519/how-to-convert-a-bytes32-to-string):

```
function bytes32ToString (bytes32 data) returns (string) {
    bytes memory bytesString = new bytes(32);
    for (uint j=0; j<32; j++) {
        byte char = byte(bytes32(uint(data) * 2 ** (8 * j)));
        if (char != 0) {
            bytesString[j] = char;
        }
    }
    return string(bytesString);
}
```

Comment: I tried the above method, I am getting empty after conversion.<br>uint256 test=1000;<br>string val=bytes32ToString(bytes32(test));<br> val i am getting as blank.

Comment: Please put your code on browser-solidity so people can check: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2835/how-to-quickly-test-a-solidity-function

Comment: consider below as my contract <br>                                              contract test {

function testIntConversion() constant returns (string test) {
    test=bytes32ToString (bytes32(1234567));
}                                                                                                            for this input I am getting output as **string test: և**. But what i wanted is functionality similar to var.toString() in java

Comment: what I needed is just typecasting from  uint to string.

Comment: Solidity is character set agnostic concerning strings.  I posted a separate answer that can help.

Answer (score 8):

[Solidity is character set agnostic concerning strings.](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/frequently-asked-questions.html#what-character-set-does-solidity-use)  There is no built-in "toString" in Solidity.  https://github.com/pipermerriam/ethereum-string-utils is a library that can help:

```
> stringUtils.uintToBytes(1234)
"1234"
```

The MIT licensed implementation is:

```
function uintToBytes(uint v) constant returns (bytes32 ret) {
    if (v == 0) {
        ret = '0';
    }
    else {
        while (v > 0) {
            ret = bytes32(uint(ret) / (2 ** 8));
            ret |= bytes32(((v % 10) + 48) * 2 ** (8 * 31));
            v /= 10;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: You did not answer the question, the question ask's for converting from uint to string not to byte32.

Answer (score 6):

Dmitriy Vinokurov answer does not work in solidity 0.8.0. This is a revised version:

```
 function uint2str(
  uint256 _i
)
  internal
  pure
  returns (string memory str)
{
  if (_i == 0)
  {
    return "0";
  }
  uint256 j = _i;
  uint256 length;
  while (j != 0)
  {
    length++;
    j /= 10;
  }
  bytes memory bstr = new bytes(length);
  uint256 k = length;
  j = _i;
  while (j != 0)
  {
    bstr[--k] = bytes1(uint8(48 + j % 10));
    j /= 10;
  }
  str = string(bstr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Oraclize code that Dmitry supplied I made a function to return a `uint` as a `string` in hex format:

```
function uint2hexstr(uint i) internal pure returns (string) {
    if (i == 0) return "0";
    uint j = i;
    uint length;
    while (j != 0) {
        length++;
        j = j >> 4;
    }
    uint mask = 15;
    bytes memory bstr = new bytes(length);
    uint k = length - 1;
    uint numStart = 48;
    uint letterStarn = 65;
    while (i != 0){
        uint curr = (i & mask);
        bstr[k--] = curr > 9 ? byte(55 + curr ) : byte(48 + curr); // 55 = 65 - 10
        i = i >> 4;
    }
    return string(bstr);
}
```

https://gist.github.com/okwme/f3a35193dc4eb9d1d0db65ccf3eb4034