# Convert (negative) int to string

Tags: solidity, string

How do I convert an "int" type value (including negative integers) to a "string" type value in Solidity? I suppose I could convert it into a bytes32, and then convert it to a string, but I feel that it would cost a lot of gas. What is the least expensive way to do this?

Comment: Related: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6591/conversion-of-uint-to-string

Answer (score 1):

Hey there is no explicit int to string conversion in solidity. You could use a function like:

```
function toBytes(int x, int digits) returns (bytes b) {
    b = new bytes(digits);
    for (uint i = 0; i < digits; i++)
        b[i] = byte(uint8(uint(x));
}
```

Comment: Please focus on an answer for the actual question.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    function _uintToString(uint value) private pure returns (string memory) {
        if (value == 0) {
            return "0";
        }
        uint temp = value;
        uint digits;
        while (temp != 0) {
            ++digits;
            temp /= 10;
        }
        bytes memory buffer = new bytes(digits);
        while (value != 0) {
            --digits;
            buffer[digits] = bytes1(uint8(48 + uint(value % 10)));
            value /= 10;
        }

        return string(buffer);
    }

    function uintToString(uint value) internal pure returns (string memory) {
        return _uintToString(value);
    }

    /*
     * @dev Converts a `uint` to its ASCII `string` decimal representation.
     * @param `denominator` MUST be either exactly 1, or evenly divisible by 10.
     */
    function uintToString(uint value, uint denominator) internal pure returns (string memory str) {
        // Inspired by OraclizeAPI's implementation - MIT licence
        // https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/blob/b42146b063c7d6ee1358846c198246239e9360e8/oraclizeAPI_0.4.25.sol

        if (denominator % 10 > 0) {
            denominator -= denominator % 10;
        }

        if (denominator == 0) {
            denominator = 1;
        }

        // String containing whole numbers only.
        str = _uintToString(value / denominator);

        if (denominator > 9) {
            uint decimalToShow;

            // Let's generate a nice, clear error message with the proper decimals.
            // We need to use assembly to achieve a proper, non-overflowing modulo.
            assembly { decimalToShow := mod(value, denominator) }

            // Now generate the decimals string, fixed to the number of global `decimals`.
            string memory strDecimals = _uintToString(decimalToShow);

            if (decimalToShow > 0) {
                for (; decimalToShow < denominator / 10; decimalToShow *= 10) {
                    strDecimals = string.concat("0", strDecimals);
                }
            }

            // Lastly, assemble the string.
            str = string.concat(str, ".", strDecimals);
        }
        return str;
    }

    function intToString(int value) internal pure returns (string memory) {
        return intToString(value, 1);
    }

    function intToString(int value, uint denominator) internal pure returns (string memory) {
        if (value < 0) {
            // Convert the `value` negative and signed integer to a positive
            // uint by multiplying it by -1. Affix the negative signer "-" string
            // designation as its suffix upon return.
            return string.concat("-", uintToString(uint(-1 * value), denominator));
        }
        return uintToString(uint(value), denominator);
    }
```

This lets you convert either uint256 or int256 to a string in Solidity 0.8.x. If you're using a smaller memory value such as uint8, you might need to cast it prior to invocation like so: `uintToString(uint(myUint8Variable)) --> string memory`.

Also provided are overloaded functions such that inside Solidity you may use whichever is most convenient: Either include an explicit denominator to print `1.151100 USDC` or omit the denominator to print the unadulterated number such as `1151100 USDC`.

The four functions with an `internal` visibility are intended for access. The `_uintToString()` function should not be explicitly used unless you desire to restructure the system. The `internal` visibility permits you to put them in a Library and link them across an entire smart contract ecosystem like I've done at Triple Confirmation.

Hope this helps!
Cheers

[image: intToString() correctly parses negative integers]