# Parse an Integer to a String in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

How can I parse an integer (uint) to a string in solidity?

This is what I have attempted to do so far:

```
function bytes32ToString (bytes32 data) returns (string) {
    bytes memory bytesString = new bytes(32);
    for (uint j=0; j<32; j++) {
      byte char = byte(bytes32(uint(data) * 2 ** (8 * j)));
      if (char != 0) {
        bytesString[j] = char;
      }
    }
    return string(bytesString);
  }
```

But the following line returns an error:

```
string myString= bytes32ToString(bytes32(myInteger));
```

Type string memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type string storage pointer.

Why is this?

Comment: Does [this](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6591/conversion-of-uint-to-string) answer your question ?

Comment: I am getting an error with that code. I have updated my question with the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code :

```
function bytes32ToString (bytes32 data) returns (string) {
    bytes memory bytesString = new bytes(32);
    for (uint j=0; j<32; j++) {
      byte char = byte(bytes32(uint(data) * 2 ** (8 * j)));
      if (char != 0) {
        bytesString[j] = char;
      }
    }

    return string(bytesString);
  }

   function My_integ(bytes32 myInteger) returns (string){

        string memory myString= bytes32ToString( myInteger );
return myString;
   }
```

[image]

Comment: Still get the same error

Comment: @Pabi what error ?

Comment: it works for me perfectly check the pic in the answer. you resolve the error using  memory  keyword

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It works.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;
contract UintToStr {  
     function UintToString(uint v) constant returns (string) {
          bytes32 ret;
            if (v == 0) {
                 ret = '0';
            }
            else {
                 while (v > 0) {
                      ret = bytes32(uint(ret) / (2 ** 8));
                      ret |= bytes32(((v % 10) + 48) * 2 ** (8 * 31));
                      v /= 10;
                 }
            }

            bytes memory bytesString = new bytes(32);
            for (uint j=0; j<32; j++) {
                 byte char = byte(bytes32(uint(ret) * 2 ** (8 * j)));
                 if (char != 0) {
                      bytesString[j] = char;
                 }
            }

            return string(bytesString);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an import of a library that makes it possible with a int-to-string function, taken from [How to convert uint to string in solidity?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69860971/11154841).

```
solidity ^0.8.0

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";

Strings.toString(myUINT)
```