# How to convert signed integer to string?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain, contract-design

I want to convert a signed integer to string.

Is the only way to use uint2str() and then use a string library function, e.g., strings, concat() to concat the sign “-“?. Or is there more efficient way?

Comment: You can find answer [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6591/conversion-of-uint-to-string) it is duplicate question.

Comment: Your answer is for unsigned int...?