# tokenId (uint256) not returning correctly

Tags: openzeppelin, uint256, returndata

In my tokenURI function, I have it setup to return the tokenId that is being called for, but when I run the method I get a symbol.

```
function tokenURI(uint256 _tokenId) public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
    require(_exists(_tokenId), "ERC721Metadata: URI query for nonexistent token");
    return string(abi.encodePacked(_baseURI(), "/", _tokenId, ".json"));
```

Here is the response I get when I call this function in Etherscan.

[image]

Is it not possible to return tokenId as a uint256 off  chain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `abi.encodePacked()` encodes `uint256` as a raw bytes sequence. In order to make it output `/1234.json` you have to convert an `uint256` to an decimal string.

For example using `uint2str` from this question [Conversion of uint to string](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6591/conversion-of-uint-to-string) it will look like this:

```
return string(
    abi.encodePacked(_baseURI(), 
        "/",
        uint2str(_tokenId),
        ".json"));
```