# mstore8 assembly instruction makes call goes out of gas

Tags: solidity, out-of-gas, assembly

My solidity code example:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

library TestLibrary {
    function sz_varint(uint256 i) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 count = 1;
        assembly {
            i := shr(7, i)
            for {} gt(i, 0) {} {
                i := shr(7, i)
                count := add(count, 1)
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    function encode_varint_assembly(uint256 x, uint256 p, bytes memory bs) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 sz = 0;
        assembly {
            let bsptr := add(bs, p)
            let byt := and(x, 0x7f)
            for {} gt(shr(7, x), 0) {} {
                mstore8(bsptr, or(0x80, byt))
                bsptr := add(bsptr, 1)
                sz := add(sz, 1)
                x := shr(7, x)
                byt := and(x, 0x7f)
            }
            mstore8(bsptr, byt)
            sz := add(sz, 1)
        }
        return sz;
    }
    function encode_varint_assembly_nomstore8(uint256 x, uint256 p, bytes memory bs) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 sz = 0;
        assembly {
            let bsptr := add(bs, p)
            let byt := and(x, 0x7f)
            for {} gt(shr(7, x), 0) {} {
                //mstore8(bsptr, or(0x80, byt))
                bsptr := add(bsptr, 1)
                sz := add(sz, 1)
                x := shr(7, x)
                byt := and(x, 0x7f)
            }
            //mstore8(bsptr, byt)
            sz := add(sz, 1)
        }
        return sz;
    }
    function encode_varint(uint256 x, uint256 p, bytes memory bs) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 tmp = x;
        uint256 idx = p;
        bytes1 byt = bytes1(uint8(tmp & 0x7f));
        while (tmp > 0x7f) {
            bs[idx] = byt | 0x80;
            tmp = tmp >> 7;
            byt = bytes1(uint8(tmp & 0x7f));
            idx += 1;
        }
        bs[idx] = byt;
        return idx - p + 1;
    }
}

contract TestContract {
    function encode_varint_assembly(uint256 x) public pure returns(bytes memory) {
        uint256 sz = TestLibrary.sz_varint(x);
        bytes memory buffer = new bytes(sz);
        TestLibrary.encode_varint_assembly(x, 0, buffer);
        return buffer;
    }
    function encode_varint_assembly_nomstore8(uint256 x) public pure returns(bytes memory) {
        uint256 sz = TestLibrary.sz_varint(x);
        bytes memory buffer = new bytes(sz);
        TestLibrary.encode_varint_assembly_nomstore8(x, 0, buffer);
        return buffer;
    }
    function encode_varint(uint256 x) public pure returns(bytes memory) {
        uint256 sz = TestLibrary.sz_varint(x);
        bytes memory buffer = new bytes(sz);
        TestLibrary.encode_varint(x, 0, buffer);
        return buffer;
    }
}
```

try running some unit tests in go using `abigen` here it's my go code

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/abi/bind"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/abi/bind/backends"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto"
)

func main() {
    auth, client := setup()
    _, _, entry, err := DeployTestContract(auth, client)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    client.Commit()

    res, err := entry.EncodeVarint(nil, big.NewInt(10))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("EncodeVarint", res)
    res, err = entry.EncodeVarintAssemblyNomstore8(nil, big.NewInt(10))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("EncodeVarintAssemblyNomstore8", res)
    res, err = entry.EncodeVarintAssembly(nil, big.NewInt(10))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("EncodeVarintAssembly", res)
}

func setup() (*bind.TransactOpts, *backends.SimulatedBackend) {
    gAlloc := make(map[common.Address]core.GenesisAccount, 1)
    deployerKey, err := crypto.GenerateKey()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    deployerAuth := bind.NewKeyedTransactor(deployerKey)
    gAlloc[deployerAuth.From] = core.GenesisAccount{Balance: big.NewInt(1000000000000000000)} // 1 eth
    client := backends.NewSimulatedBackend(gAlloc, 1000000000000000000) // 1 eth
    return deployerAuth, client
}
```

versions are

```bash
$ solc --version
solc, the solidity compiler commandline interface
Version: 0.8.9+commit.e5eed63a.Linux.g++
$ abigen --version
abigen version 1.10.0-stable
```

a snippet of my `go.mod`

```
module experiments/solidity_varint
go 1.17

require github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum v1.10.0
...
```

output of running the main is:

```bash
EncodeVarint [10]
EncodeVarintAssemblyNomstore8 [0]
panic: out of gas

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    /home/giulio/go/src/experiments/solidty_varint/main.go:34 +0x24b
exit status 2
```

Apparently the `mstore8` instruction makes the whole call goes out of gas. Is there any reason?? Where is the error in my `mstore8` assembly call?

Note:
This `varint` functions are decoding function for a protobuf solidity runtime decoder I am working with/on

Answer (score 1):

You are not really running out of gas your are seeing an EVM panic.

I think it is coming from overwriting the arrays lengths (see [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/48582/84305)).

In your implementation :

```
  function encode_varint_assembly(uint256 x, uint256 p, bytes memory bs) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 sz = 0;
        assembly {
            let bsptr := add(bs, p)
            let byt := and(x, 0x7f)
            for {} gt(shr(7, x), 0) {} {
                mstore8(bsptr, or(0x80, byt))
                bsptr := add(bsptr, 1)
                sz := add(sz, 1)
                x := shr(7, x)
                byt := and(x, 0x7f)
            }
            mstore8(bsptr, byt)
            sz := add(sz, 1)
        }
        return sz;
    }
```

I think that this line is the problem :

```
let bsptr := add(bs,p)
```

As you call your functions with p = 0 from your TestContract you are effectively writing : `let bsptr := add(bs, 0)` but bs being an array, bsptr point to the array length. Rewriting it will send the EVM into panic.

Changing it to :

```
let bsptr := add(bs,32)
```

makes bsptr points to the actual data of the array. (skipping the first 32bytes reserved for the read only array size)

With this change calls to encode_varint and encore_varint_assembly are both successfull and return the same value. I don't know much about protobuf so I cannot really validate the content of the returned value...

If I understand correctly, p might be an offset in the array where you'd want to write your encoded integer x. If so, this might be more correct regarding what you want to do :

```
let bsptr := add(bs, add(32, p))
```