# What does add(source, 32) do in solidity?

Tags: solidity, assembly, bytes32

I understand what `add()` does. It used used in the assembly to perform additions. My question is why are we adding 32 here? What is the purpose of doing so?

The full code is [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/9152/44794)

Answer (score 6):

To better understand it is better to include part of the function

```
function stringToBytes32(string memory source) public pure returns (bytes32 result) {
    // ..

    assembly {
        result := mload(add(source, 32))
    }
}
```

`source` is a memory string so the first 32 bytes contains the length and data follows. Then `add(source, 32)` skips the size portion of the string, and points to the data.